# fractional power of a fraction - $\log(s/s_o)^{2/3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have an expression $\log(s/s_o)^{2/3}$

I would like to rewrite this as a difference of logs using the rules of logs.  If there was no exponent I could rewrite this as $\log(s)-\log(s_o)$. But the fractional exponent is confusing me.

I know that if I was dealing with a whole number, e.g. $\log(x)^{2/3}$ then I could just rewrite as $\sqrt[3]{\log(x)^2}$.

I don't understand how to combine these two rules here?

How can I rewrite $\log(s/s_o)^{2/3}$ as a difference of logs?

Comment: Is there a minus sign before the logarithm...or not? And what you say you know is wrong.

Comment: (1) I have edited your post to clean up the notation a bit.  In general, using `\frac` in inline text spreads out lines and creates very small, hard to read symbols.  It is generally better to avoid it outside of displays (not always, but often).  (2) Do you mean $[\log(s/s_0)]^{2/3}$, or $\log( [s/s_0]^{2/3})$?  It is not clear to me which is intended...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\log\left(\frac{s}{s_0}\right)^{2/3}=\frac{2}{3}[\log s-\log s_0]=\frac{2}{3}\log s-\frac{2}{3}\log s_0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\log\left(\frac s{s_0}\right)^{2/3}=\frac23\log\frac s{s_0}\stackrel{\text{assuming}\,s,\,s_0>0}=\frac23\left(\log s-\log s_0\right)$$